# Call member function of std::map value object on insertion

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have an `std::map` of type `std::map<key, value>`.

I want to define a function f on types key

```
void f(key k){
// stuff
}
```

that does the following:

1. If there is no value v in map with an equivalent key, k`==k, then insert `std::make_pair(k, values(k))` into map.
2. If there is a value v in map with the equivalent key, k'==k, then call the member function g of v on k (v.g(k))

I have come up with two solutions, but neither are efficient for different reasons. The first:

```
auto [iter, success] = myMap.insert(k, value(k));
if (!success){
    (iter -> second).g(k);
}
```

The issue here is that I must call the constructor `value(k)` to call `insert`. If an element with key equivalent to `k` appears in the map already, then I do not need to construct an object of type `value`.

Another solution is to first use `find` to see if an element with key equivalent to `k` appears in the map. However, if no such element is present, then I will need to search through myMap again to find the insertion point of `(k, value(k))`.

Is there a way to do this that searches through myMap once and doesn't call the constructor of `value` when it doesn't need to?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I updated my question to provide more details. If there is a reason for it to remain closed, please let me know.

Comment: Did you know about the member function `emplace`?  Works like `insert`, except instead of an instance of `value_type` which will be moved into the map, you provide arguments to the constructor of `value_type`.... or things which can be converted to such arguments.... and `emplace` directly constructs the object in-place without making a copy/move or having to have a pattern instance prepared in advance.

Comment: In your case, where `value(k)` is valid, I think you will just do `auto [iter, success] = myMap.emplace(k, {k});` and proceed like you show with insert

Comment: I am aware of ```emplace```. I do not believe it solves my problem because it has the problem I described above in the example with insert. My concern is not that I am copying/moving, but that I don't need to do ```values(k)``` (suffer the cost of calling the constructor) if there is an object in myMap with key equivalent to ```k```. In that case, I just want to find the object and call the member function ```g``` on its value.

Comment: Yes, based on your second comment, I believe ```emplace``` solves my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in C++17 efficient:

```
auto [iter, success] = myMap.try_emplace(k, k);
if (!success){
    (iter -> second).g(k);
}
```

According to the manual it inserts in-place if the key does not exist, does nothing if the key exists.
[std::map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>::try_emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace)